# Question on what Kira said to Vedek Bareil

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

E2, S2. You get:

> BAREIL: It's not important. I was just wondering if I was part of yours.
>
> KIRA: No. No, you weren't.

I'm wondering why Kira denies, considering that in a previous scene she clearly met him in her vision.

The only idea that pops into my head is for modesty, reserve, shyness, discretion.

Is there some other specific reason?

Comment: Because she's embarrassed about admitting to the fact that she basically had a sex dream about him

Comment: He is a priest, after all. Actually wait a minute — DS9 did the Hot Priest thing like 20 years before *Fleabag*. It was so ahead of its time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## She lied to avoid having to give away more details about the vision.

This is how her vision ends:

> **BAREIL**: Don't listen to him, Nerys. Allow yourself to hear them. They are calling to you.
> (**Kira is naked**)
> **WINN**: Blasphemy.
> **BAREIL**: Listen to them, Nerys.
> **KIRA**: Help me to hear them. I don't know how.
> **BAREIL**: But you do.
> (A **naked Bareil** is behind her.)
> **BAREIL**: You do.
> (**Kira leans against Bareil**)
> **BAREIL**: You do.
> (**Just as they are about to kiss**, the vision ends)

*(DS9: The Circle)*

So she basically had a sex dream about him. This is what he explains about *his* visions of *her*:

> **BAREIL**: You don't want to talk about it.
> **KIRA**: No.
> **BAREIL**: Can I tell you something **very personal**?
> **KIRA**: I'm not a Vedek but I can keep a secret.
> **BAREIL**: The last time I encountered the third orb, **you were a part of my vision.**
> **KIRA**: Me?
> **BAREIL**: **It's the reason that I came to the station, to invite you here**.
> **KIRA**: What part did I play in your vision?
> **BAREIL**: **It's not important**. I was just wondering if I was part of yours.
> **KIRA**: No. No, you weren't.

*(DS9: The Circle)*

So Bareil saw her in a vision and considered that experience very personal, and important enough to meet her. Since his vision is so important to him, he would definitely had any follow up questions about her visions. This would make a very awkward discussion to have with a priest, so she lied to avoid that discussion.

Comment: "a very awkward discussion to have with a priest" - his role as a priest might inappropriately bias our perception of the situation. In plenty of our Earth cultures, we have certain connotations for what "being a priest" would be about, yet with Bajor being an alien culture, it is not clear whether these connotations actually hold. As far as I remember, no part of Bareil's flirting and later relationship with Kira appeared to be seen as unconventional or unbecoming for a Vedek by other Bajorans.

Comment: I see your point, and I offer you two additional thoughts that have crossed my mind: 1) Regardless of conventions, Kira herself sees it as inappropriate, given that in her vision, Winn says "Blasphemy!" the second her vision turns into a sex dream.

Comment: 2) It might not be unlikely that she assumed that Bareil had a sex dream about her as well - he frames it as very personal and refuses to tell her which part she had in that vision. Priest or not, if both had sex dreams about the other, things would be very awkward.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I give you +1 becouse your observation is acute. Nevertheless I give you a not-thanks (or a not-benediction if I were a priest) for the spoiler☺️

Comment: Yes, I can accept this essentially for the part of embarrassment (what I initially thought), and maybe also for avoiding to give him further extra erotic parts details (it would have sufficed to omit them, and tell him  the rest..); but more remote hypothesis; I guess modesty, decency, respect and scruple reasons depending on his "priest" status are frustrated by @Mapper's observation. They may act, but independently from his status: for example protestant priests can be married..

Comment: Moreover we can consider that the orb is *the orb of **prophecy** and change*. She may think, 'He's dreamed of me, I've dreamed that situation, so in the future we.....' as @Mapper gently suggested me